# How to behave in a toxic work environment?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I am working in a consultancy firm for 2 months and it's my first job. From the first day I started working in here, I've found myself in office politics. My team is new and made up from 4-5 people. Our manager is ineffective since he does not know anything about our branch. He just sells the projects and he is not really interested about who does what. The problem is, the team lacks of discipline and work ethics. They show themselves like they are working really really hard and they stay up late at office everyday. They are stressful all the time but they don't just focus and work, at least, for 1-2 hours.

For once or twice I tried to say "let's get to work" in a sugar-coated way but they didn't like it. And someone, X, is a little experienced about this area. X scolded me for asking my colleague a know-how question about one of X's task. I warned X not to do this again in a clear way. But now, she is calling and telling me "You have made mistakes in your task but I fixed it last night" in a nervous way. She was supposed to test this in previous weeks, not just right before the User Acceptance Test! Her lack of planning, should not constitute and emergency or stress on me. I already escalated this problem to my manager, he knows this, they are constantly looking for new candidates but the projects should go on.

An expert just joined us for giving support for our projects and he is very aware of this problem. He helps me a lot in every way, telling me that this environment will change. But in the mean time how should I behave? I am pretty aware that they are backbiting me and sometimes I feel lonely but I don't want to hang out with them. I feel demoralized and tired most of the days. How should I work with them? Am I making a mistake for being blunt and explicit?

Comment: *How to behave in a toxic work environment?*  Leave it.

Comment: There are two possible management styles available: top down which means, that the boss has the control or bottom up which is equal to that the boss tries to help his employees and they are helping the customers. Which description fits to your situation better?

Answer (score 5):

Mental pressure scars from toxic environment is long lasting and change you in a wrong way.

There is NO good reason to stay in the toxic environment.
If you cant say with certainty, that team would be completely disbanded and you will get to communicate with different people,

Change job.

Answer (score 5):

This is your first job and you've been there for two months. You should not be telling people to "get to work". There is a difference between being blunt and overstepping. If you are careful about it you may be able to repair your work relationships and end up with a better work environment.

However it is possible you may not be able to. It is also possible that the environment is still irreparably toxic. Only you can evaluate if it is worth sticking it out and trying to make this job a good one or if it will just be awful for you long-term.